# How to use RequireJS AngularJS and Google Visualization API

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, google-visualization, angularjs-directive

Wondering if anyone has gotten RequireJS, ANgularJS and Google Visualization API working together. I cannot seem to get the charts to function properly. 
The main problem I am having is that the google.setOnLoadCallback() is not running.
below is my code. I am not sold entirely on Google Visualization API if there is another chart library that is easier to use with RequireJS.

```
define([ 'jquery'],function ( $) {
return function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',

        link: function (scope, lElement, attrs) {

            console.log("loaded google jsapi");

              console.log("google");

            google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});


            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
            function drawChart() {
                console.log("we are in the call back");
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                    ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
                    ['2004',  1000,      400],
                    ['2005',  1170,      460],
                    ['2006',  660,       1120],
                    ['2007',  1030,      540]
                ]);

                var options = {
                    title: 'Company Performance',
                    vAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
                };

                var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(lElement[0]);
                chart.draw(data, options);
            }

            console.log("called google.load for visualization");
        }
    }
}
});
```

If anyone has gotten eh three working together perhaps you can explain or post a  link to a JSFidlle.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if this will fix your problem or not, but the google loader has known issues with being called inside other functions.  Users in other environments have had success setting the callback function inside the load call instead of in the `#setOnLoadCallback` method.  Try using this:

```
define(['jquery'],function ( $) {
    return function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, lElement, attrs) {
                function drawChart() {
                    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                        ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
                        ['2004',  1000,      400],
                        ['2005',  1170,      460],
                        ['2006',  660,       1120],
                        ['2007',  1030,      540]
                    ]);

                    var options = {
                        title: 'Company Performance',
                        vAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
                    };

                    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(lElement[0]);
                    chart.draw(data, options);
                }
                google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"], callback: drawChart});
            }
        }
    }
});
```